# Unable to compile copy-pasted code from ethereum.org/crowdsale in OSX ethereum wallet

Tags: solidity

while copy-pasting the code from ethereum.org/crowdsale in mx OSX ethereum wallet (on test network Rinkeby), I get the following compiler error report:

```
 No visibility specified. Defaulting to "public".
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount);
```

If I replace `;` with `Public`{}`, the error moves to function Crowdsale( with compiler error report:

```
function Crowdsale(
    ^
Spanning multiple lines.
```

I believe this is the same issue asked in "similar Questions" facing issue in creating crowdsale... (on hold)

Thanx...

Answer (score 2):

It's because the compiler has evolved a little since the source code was published.

Insert the modifier `public` into each function after input arguments and before the `;` or `{}` and the errors should start disappearing.

Example:

```
function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) public ;

function doSomething(args, args) public { ... }
```

Hope it helps.